# Why is mediaelement.js Wordpress plugin not showing video in Safari?

Tags: wordpress, html, plugins, mediaelement.js

We are using the mediaelement.js Wordpress plugin for our videos and it works great in IE and FoxFire, but only shows a black box in Safari.  Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

http://www.bluelogicentertainment.com/lccs2/

Thanks.

-Taama

Comment: Your page works in my safari (version 5.1.1)  Which version are you using?